# Data Normalization in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, normalization

I have a table in mysql:

```
user_item_text
    username, item, text
```

I want to normalize the data into three tables:

```
users
    user_id, username

items
    item_id, item_name

text
    text_id, text_name
```

How can I use the existing `user_item_text` table to create the three tables as described? There are around 800000 records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the example how to handle one table "user":

```
create table users(
   user_id int not null auto_increment, 
   username varchar(50), 
   primary key(user_id), 
   index ind_user_username(username)
) engine = XXX;

insert into users(username) select distinct username from user_item_text

alter table user_item_text add user_id integer null

update user_item_text uit join users u on uit.username = u.username
set uit.user_id = u.user_id

alter table user_item_text drop column username
```

maybe you will be need to add the following steps before runing the last `update`:

1. adding index on `user_item_text.username` field to make update run faster
2. unique index on `users.username` instead of ordinary index
3. `user_item_index.user_id` should have FK

Hope it helps.

ps. i didn't test query. They just showing you general approach.

Answer (score 1):

Create the tables and then use an insert combined with a select. As far as I know it is possible to use a table for insert.

For example:
Users and the primary key is autoincrement

```
    Insert into users (username) Select username from user_item_text
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/insert-select.html